# UWP Windows IoT Core Stream Routing

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

I would like to find out if Windows IoT Core supports [Stream Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/stream-routing). Otherwise, is there any other work around for similar result? 
I have multiple USB audio adapter connected to my RaspberryPi and would like route the different 'capture' device(s) to diff 'render' device(s) .. like mixing the audio etc.
Any advise please.. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the APIs in [Windows.Media.Audio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.audio?view=winrt-19041) namespace to create audio graphs for audio routing, mixing, and processing scenarios.An [audio graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs) is a set of interconnected audio nodes through which audio data flows. Please refer to this [AudioGraph sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation).